# Reordenar div quando o navegador é redimensionado

Tags: html, div, redimensionamento

Como posso fazer com que a div "col-md-3" seja a primeira a ser exibida quando o navegador é redimensionado?

Repare que usei a classe "order-last" para que ela seja exibido por ultimo em resolução normal, porém, quando redimensiono o navegador, quero que essa div seja a primeira a ser exibida.

Segue codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-BR">
    <head>
        <title>Exemplo</title>
        <meta charset="uff-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 order-last">
                        <!--Menu-->
                        <p>
                            1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed malesuada ex. Nam in ullamcorper tortor, ac tempor erat.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <!--Texto-->
                        <p>
                            2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed malesuada ex. Nam in ullamcorper tortor, ac tempor erat.
                        </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Para melhor compreensão, seguem as imagens abaixo.
Até aqui esta tudo bem. Este é o comportamento que quero quando o navegador esta com a resolução "normal".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o navegador é redimensionado, as divs ficam desta forma. Porem quero que a div com o paragrafo "1" seja apresentado primeiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -4, accepted):

No lugar de utilizar `order-last` utilize `order-first order-sm-last`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou.

Comment: Eu fiz alguns teste e utilizando media queries também consegui chegar no mesmo resultado. Porém tive que remover a classe "order-last" e inserir a funcionalidade "order" dentro da media querie